# Is it possible to add angularized html tags and attributes in a directive based on model data in Angularjs?

Tags: forms, angularjs

I want to build a directive that will build form inputs based on a nested object of settings that include the input type, model to bind, and html attributes. I have been pounding my head and, perhaps, am close to concluding that this is something Angular is not equipped to do. I would like to build a directive that could take an array of objects like:

```
[{
    "label":"When did it happen",
    "model": $scope.event.date,
    "element":"input",
    "type": "date",
    "options":{
       "class":"big",
       "required": true,
     },
  },{
    "label":"How did it happen?",
    "model": $scope.event.cause,
    "element":"textarea",
    "options":{
      "cols":45,
      "rows":55,
    },
  },{
    "label":"How many times did it happen?",
    "model": $scope.event.times,
    "element":"input",
    "options":{},
  }],
```

I have struggled through many different aspects of directives. I keep running across a few issues.

- Neither the template nor the controller directive functions have access to any sort of scope that could reach any sort of data--most especially my array I've made. This means that I can't decide how to build my DOM (i.e. tag types and attributes) until later.
- All compiling is done before the linking function. I am able to manipulate the DOM in the linking function but none of it is angularized. This means if I add a required attribute angular's ngValidate is not aware of it. If I try and change the tag type, I reset lose my model binding etc.

It seems that this is just the way angular runs. Is there no good way to affect the DOM tag types and attributes based on model data without specifying everything out specifically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$scope.event = {
    date: new Date(),
    cause:'It was the colonel in the kitchen with the revolver',
    time:5, //...
    $metadata: data
};
```

Where `data` here is simply the array you have already shown. (apart from the model property which would just be a string representing the property of the event, like so:

```
{
    "label":"When did it happen",
    "model":'date',
    "element":"input",
    "type": "date",
    "options":{
      "class":"big",
      "required": true,
     }
}
```

Then your directive would simply access the property given it on the parent scope. (`event`) And process the metadata into a usable template. Which could then get compiled.

Here is such a directive, and the directive...

```
myApp.directive('contentForm',function($compile,$interpolate){
  var template = "<span class='lbl'>{{label}}</span><{{element ||'input'}} {{options}}"+
             " ng-model='{{root+'.'+model}}'></{{element}}>";                 

  function linkerFunction(scope,element,attrs){
    if(!scope[attrs.contentForm])return;
    var metadata = scope[attrs.contentForm].$metadata || false;
    if(!metadata)return;
    element.html(getHtml(metadata,attrs.contentForm));
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link:linkerFunction
  };
  //interpolate the template with each set of metadata
  function getHtml(metadata,root){
    var interpolation = $interpolate(template);
    var html = '';
    if(angular.isArray(metadata)){
      for(var i = 0; i < metadata.length; i++){
        metadata[i].root = root;
        metadata[i].options = processOptions(metadata[i].options);
        html += interpolation(metadata[i]) + '</br>'
      }
    }else{
      html = interpolation(metadata);
      metadata.options = processOptions(metadata.options);
    }
    return html;
  }                
  // parse object into html attributes 
  function processOptions(options){
    var result = '';
    for(var key in options){
      if(options.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        result += ' '+key+"='"+options[key]+"'"
      }
    }
    return result.trim();
  } 
});
```

You'd probably want to change the template. I seem to have forgotten to put in a type. But that should be fairly straight forward. I hope this helps!

Comment: This is incredible. You are the man Caleb. I spent way too much time on this before you came to my aid. I learned a lot. Thanks soooooo much.